# Fitness function bottleneck resolution, C#

Tags: c#, function, fitness

```
private  void CalculateFitness(TimeTable timeTable)
{
    int score = 0, DAYS_NUM = 5;

    score = timeTable.Exams.SelectMany(exam => exam.Students)
         .GroupBy(s => s)
         .Select(g => Connections(g.Count()))
         .Sum();
    timeTable.Fitness = score;
}

int Connections(int corners)
{
    // 0+1+2+...+(corners-1)
    return corners * (corners - 1) / 2;
}
```

Comment: that variable assignment is the bottleneck of your application??

Comment: It's hard to suggest improvements without knowing the types involved, the relationships etc. I'm sure there's a better approach, but we can't really help much without more details.

Comment: I don't think so...this is an app for physical fitness, so maybe it's supposed to help people who have "bottle" necks.

Comment: Delayed execution of LINQ on that line? I guess the intersect is the real bottleneck - however he's calling the Count() inside the loop so it really ought not be delayed.

Comment: The last line is cheap compared to the rest of the function, unless the setter of `timeTable.Fitness` is very expensive. But you didn't post that one.

Comment: Is this a simple object you've written or e.g. derived from a genetic programming framework where the Fitness setter might be very complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't your function equivalent to this:

```
score = timeTable.Exams.SelectMany(exam=>exam.Students)
                 .GroupBy(s=>s)
                 .Select(g=>Connections(g.Count()))
                 .Sum();
```

with helper function

```
int Connections(int corners)
{
  //Formula for number of sides in a complete graph
  //http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_graph
  // 0+1+2+...+(corners-1)
  return corners*(corners-1)/2;
}
```

This should be linear runtime in `timeTable.Exams.Sum(exam=>exam.Student.Count())` whereas yours looks quadratic to me.

Comment: Ok timetable is a list of exam objects with each exam containing a list of students. I would like to count the number of exams that contain students who have the same id. This would effectively give me a clash count. However my current code is moving very slow when i try to assign the score to the timetable.fitness

Comment: @user: Does your code give different results from mine? I calculate in how many exams each student is, and then use the `Connections` function to quickly calculate the collision count for each student, and then sum them up.

Comment: i get an ambiguous reference on g.count

Comment: Missed the () to make it a function call.

Comment: I edited the function to include your suggestions however i still have the same problem. timetabe.Fitness is a float auto-property

Comment: Does it give the same results? I haven't tested it, so I'm not 100% sure. But you didn't describe your problem well.

Comment: Yes it gives the same result performance wise when i ran ant code profiler on it. however when i remove the assignment to timetable.fitness it runs at optimal speed.